# Handling WPF button double-click in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling, double-click

I have a button in an MVVM application that is hooked up to a command in the view model. The handler for the view model command does some file I/O (particularly calling File.Copy to create or overwrite an existing file).

Now, it seems that when I double-click on the button, this command handler gets called twice. Since both handlers are now trying to access the same file to copy/overwrite it at the same time, I'm getting an IOException.

Is there anyway to deal with this situation short of catching the IOException and ignoring it? This does not seem to be a guaranteed catch although there may be unrelated problems with the rest of the system that causes that to happen.

Comment: Have you tried to use a semaphore?  You could set it around your I/O code that would block any extra incoming button clicks.  This isn't necessarily a fix. Just a catch until you do find a solution to the multi-click.

Comment: @Alan: Actually, all those questions seem to be about handling a double-click. I don't care about the handling the double click event, I just want to ignore it. Basically if there was a way to fire the command only when the click count == 1 without having to go out of the commanding system.

Comment: @CaptainBli: I've thought about using a semaphore but I was hoping it'd be something easier. :/

Comment: Ok I misunderstood, let me try to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a value in the the ViewModel to protect the code that would be running when a click occurs.  Set a value like: `bool bFileIO = false;`

Then in your handler function:

```
 if (!bFileIO)
 {
      bFileIO = true;
      //file IO here

      bFileIO = false;
 }
```

Something like that would protect the multi-clicking from trying to run multiple times.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to use the CanExecute of the command and change it to false during file io

Comment: That makes for a lot of extra code.  Though I would agree that using a `CanExecute` is a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do this since I'm using `RoutedCommand`s

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this is to have your command return false in `CanExecute` while you're executing. This will prevent the second click from happening (as your button will be disabled). If using a [`DelegateCommand` from prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx):

```cs
private readonly DelegateCommand<object> copyCommand;
private bool isCopying = false;

public MyViewModel()
{
    copyCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(
        _ => !isCopying,
        _ => 
        {
            if (isCopying) return;  // this shouldn't be required, but here for safety
            isCopying = true;
            copyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            // do copy
            isCopying = false;
            copyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the CanExecute of your command to control your button.

```
<Button Command="{Binding WriteFileCommand}" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,194,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

and the viewmodel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private bool isWritingFile = false;

    public DelegateCommand WriteFileCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool IsWritingFile
    {
        get
        {
            return isWritingFile;
        }
        set
        {
            isWritingFile = value;
            WriteFileCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        WriteFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(WriteFile, CanWriteFile);
    }

    private void WriteFile()
    {
        IsWritingFile = true;

        // write the file
        // FileStream stream = new FileStrem(...)
        //

        IsWritingFile = false;
    }
}
```